# Visual Studio 2008 & Override LanguageService for Existing File Extension

Tags: .net, javascript, visual-studio, vsx, languageservice

I write simple LanguageService for JavaScript language. Target IDE is Visual Studio 2008.
I want to run my LanguageService for .js extension file(default extension for JavaScript language). But for this extension my LanguageService don't working. When I run my LanguageService for extension .jsp(could be any extension don't supporting by VS IDE) - LanguageService working well.

My question: how to override existing LanguageService for JavaScript language?
How to disable default LanguageService for JS?

Sincerely,

Mykhaylo

Comment: I found this web page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/c5ae18bb-d784-4768-92b3-0690e9615f72
I think is good for start.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overriding the extension editor in the Tools menu?

Go to

- Tools -> Options
- Navigate to Text Editor -> File Extension
- Associate .js with your installed language service

Comment: My language service don't available in the these list. Language service is installed because my simple logic is available. Maybe I must to add some extra attributes to my Package class?